# toggle text without jquery

Tags: javascript

I want toggle my mail on click the icon. But I want make without jquery.

You have a idea ?

```
    <a id="fa-envelope"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

    <p>yolo@gmail.com</p>
```

Comment: which mail ????? what you mean by toggle in this case ???

Comment: Are you saying that upon clicking the fontawesome icon that you want the email address in the paragraph to be toggled between being hidden and being displayed? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want a completely javascript-free solution, or can it be vanilla JS without jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aiming for a completely JavaScript-free solution, you can use a hidden checkbox to achieve this.

```css
#togglebox {
  display: none;
}

#fa-envelope {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#togglebox + p {
  display: none;
  }

#togglebox:checked + p {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<link href="//fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <label for="togglebox" id="fa-envelope"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="togglebox"><p>yolo@gmail.com</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="fa-envelope" onclick="toggle(e)"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<p id="toggle_mail">yolo@gmail.com</p>
```

js

```
function toggle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("toggle_mail").innerHTML = "new email";
    return false;
}
```